# BBcode parser, size not changing

Tags: php, regex, parsing, preg-replace, bbcode

I am using a simple BBCode parser, which I have had to manipulate and add things to as it has a limited number of commands, which then I have had to extend. Everything else works perfectly, but the size is just not changing. It does not show the BBCode tags, so it is converting it to something but it is not recognising the change in the font-size I guess. Any ideas?

```
/* Size */
$match["size"] = "/\[size=([0-7]+(%|px|em)?)\](.*?)\[\/size\]/is";
$replace["size"] = "<span style=\"font-size: $1;\">$3</span>";

$bbcode = preg_replace($match, $replace, $bbcode); ....etc.
```

I put the size from 0-7 here as the size possibilities only go up to 7 in my editor...

Comment: Can you show some sample input and output and what is the exact problem you are getting ?

Comment: If there is no `%|px|em` (it is optional), there's a bare `'font-size:<number>'`, which doesn't work. Some unit of measure is required.

Comment: So say the input is [size=7]text[/size] (very large size), the output will be just text, in normal size. It is like the command does not affect it at all, but no html code is visible either

Comment: Brilliant! Fixed it, I named each size separately as: $match["size=2"] = "/\[size=2\](.*?)\[\/size\]/is";
$replace["size=2"] = "<span style=\"font-size: x-small;\">$1</span>"; and now it works beautifully.